# Print two variables without space with echo in unix

Tags: bash, unix, echo

```
VAR1=ABC;
VAR2=XYZ;
VAR3=PQR;
```

I want to print value of VAR1,VAR2 and VAR3 in a for loop.
Please help!

In a `for loop` i am trying to do `echo $VAR$i`

Expected O/P:

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

Actual Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 6):

Use an array:

```
VAR[1]=ABC
VAR[2]=XYZ
VAR[3]=PQR
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    echo ${VAR[i]}
done
```

Or, use the variable indirection:

```
VAR1=ABC
VAR2=XYZ
VAR3=PQR
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    name=VAR$i
    echo ${!name}
done
```

Comment: +1 for the variable indirection. I wasn't aware it was possible to do it like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
   eval "echo \$VAR${i}"
done
```

The key point is the `eval` command.

#### Test

```
$ VAR1=ABC; VAR2=XYZ; VAR3=PQR;
$ for i in 1 2 3; do eval "echo \$VAR${i}"; done
ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

Comment: While this approach is necessary for vanilla `sh`, `bash` provides alternatives (see [choroba's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17021297/1126841)) that don't require you to use the possibly dangerous `eval` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${VAR1}${VAR2}${VAR3}"
```

Simple as that. I don't think it make sense to create useless cycles just to concatenate several values into a string

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
echo $VAR$i
```

in for loop do

```
varx=$varx$var$i
```

and initialize varx as empty string and at end do

```
echo $varx
```

This is for printing without space as the question suggests.

Comment: This doesn't expand to the value of the three variables.